# How to graceful exit if the required verion of python is not used?

Tags: python, version, assert

I want to make python script that checks python interpreter version and execute only the required version of python.

I want to use f-string formatting only available after version 3.6 and hence prepared version check code as follows:

```
import sys

# Python version check
major, minor, micro, _, _ = sys.version_info
if (major, minor) < (3, 6):
    print("current python version: %d.%d" % (major, minor))
    print("this code requires python 3.6 for operation")
    sys.exit()
else:
    print(f"current python version:{major}.{minor:d}")

# use of f-string feature available from 3.6 version
pi = 3.141592
print(f"pi with precision 2 is {pi:.2f}")
```

My intention was to gracefully exit with error message when the required python version is not used.
But check with the script with different version of python as follows:

```sh
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
$ python ./python_version_check.py
  File "./python_version_check.py", line 16
    print(f"current python version:{major}.{minor:d}")
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
$ python3 ./python_version_check.py
  File "./python_version_check.py", line 16
    print(f"current python version:{major}.{minor:d}")
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

$ conda activate python3
$ python --version
Python 3.6.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.
$ python ./python_version_check.py
current python version:3.6
pi with precision 2 is 3.14
```

In stead of graceful exit, it makes SyntaxErr under 3.6 version python.

I also tried with assert statement  in the version check part as follows:

```py
assert sys.version_info >= (3, 6), \
        "this code requires python 3.6 for operation"
```

but this code does not work as intended since "The current code generator emits no code for an assert statement when optimization is requested at compile time."

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) says that assert expression can better be described as being equivalent to

```py
if __debug__:
   if not expression: raise AssertionError
```

How do I modifiy above code to grecefully exit with error message printing on python version under 3.6 as intended?

Comment: You can't have code that uses potentially wrong syntax and check it at runtime... it will fail *at compile time*. The file fails to even parse.

Answer (score 0):

You may use print, inside of try catch for different python printing versions.

```
import sys

# Python version check
major, minor, micro, _, _ = sys.version_info
if (major, minor) < (3, 6):
    try:
        print("current python version: %d.%d" % (major, minor))
        print("this code requires python 3.6 for operation")
    except:
        print "current python version: %d.%d" % (major, minor)
        print "this code requires python 3.6 for operation"
    finally:
        exit()
else:
    print(f"current python version:{major}.{minor:d}")

# use of f-string feature available from 3.6 version
pi = 3.141592
print(f"pi with precision 2 is {pi:.2f}")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your code also generate ```SyntaxError``` when running the code on python verion 2 and python version below 3.6.
I want to grace exit instead of generating ```SyntaxErr``` when the required python version (3.6) is not used.

Comment: This will not work, `SyntaxErrors` are not runtime errors, they will not be caught by a try-except. It happens *at compile time*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 
Thanks for your comment. Is python interpreter language?  Does it require to compile whole code before execution instead of execution line by line?

Comment: Pretty much no modern language is purely interpreted from source code. Python source code is compiled to bytecode and that bytecode is run on a bytecode interpreter. It is during the bytecode compilation step that this parsing error will occur

Comment: With googling of "Is Python compiled or interpreted?", I found it that eventhough python is known as interpreter langugage, it requires to source code to byte code (*.pyc). Please refer to 
Yogesh Chaurse comment at [this url](https://www.quora.com/Is-Python-compiled-or-interpreted-or-both) for detailed explantion. Hence my requirement cannot be realized with python code. Now, I understand the behind procedures when execute the python code.